# Astronomy on a maximally spinning Earth

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, astronomy

Let there be an earth-sized planet with a rotational period of just over 3 hours and 38 minutes described by David Hammen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136503/103442) . On this oblate spheroid, with nights lasting for an hour and 49ish minutes, would the observational skills of an alien Galileo be diminished or enhanced? What advantages or disadvantages would it pose? Would heliocentrism be harder or easier to defend?

Answer (score 3):

Astronomy would be harder because the period when it was really dark would be pretty short. Much shorter than the 1:19 between sun down and sun up. It wouldn't be impossible, since you could just aim the scope and wait another 3 hours for it to get dark again. It would take a bit of patience, but it would also have an advantage of not needing to happen when others are sleeping, since any kind of sleep cycle longer than a nap might take several days.
So you could get up whenever, do some stuff around the house, go out at dark and make your observations, go work on some other stuff, go out and make observations, and so on until bed time.

I'm not really sure that heliocentrism would be affected either way. The same problem arises... how to prove the Earth orbits the Sun, and not the other way around?

The biggest thing that would have made this a moot question is if either Mars or Venus had a large moon like Luna, since something like that would be visible to the naked eye early on.

A fast orbit just proves that the sun is in a big hurry to get around the earth, but nothing more.

On a side note, if this planet had a tilt like Earths, the best observatories would be located closer to or maybe at the poles, in order to take advantage of the longer nights this would provide

Comment: The stars move faster too don't they?

Comment: @King-Ink Yeah, everything above the atmosphere would rise and fall at the same fast pace. The sun and stars aren't moving of course, just the observer. I assume that people that want to look at stars through a telescope are going to get really good at finding stars quickly, or they won't do it very long.

Comment: They would move at a good clip  .65 degrees a second. I see  tracking anything a good distance south of Polaris them with a high powered scope as being an athletic feat.

Comment: When you say Luna, you mean the moon, right? Because I don't know anyone who normally calls the sun sol or says luna.

Comment: I call her Men but we have been friends a long time. Luna and Sol are the formal names of the sun and earth's moon.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon yeah, Luna is another name for the moon. It might have been confusing to say "if the had large moons like the moon". Maybe not, but that's why I used it.

Comment: You might have said our moon, but Luna is fine. I just don't normally hear it, so it confused me.

Answer (score 0):

You would need better/faster stabilizers and tracking technology and it would be hard to take any really long exposures but in general astronomy wouldn't change. You would make frequent small measurements rather than infrequent long ones but otherwise continue as normal.

Comment: How about bronze age navigators?

Comment: That's a separate question in its own right, certainly too big to discuss in comments. If you ask it as a question though it's an interesting subject :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the technology of Galileo's time, it would be harder. Making sense of the observations was in stages. Stationary stars, the variable stars, slowly changing sun positions. With primitive timing and observational apparatus, observations that had slower apparent change would favor the crude hourly timing combined with the more precise calendar (seasonal, annual, decade long) elapsed time measurements.

A 4 hour day, but how long of a year?

Comment: 1178 local day year 356 of our days